# How to Merge Lists of Lists

Tags: python, list

I am working in Python for a coding project. I am stuck on something that seems like it should be a simple fix but haven't had much luck.

Let's say I have two lists, each consisting of smaller lists...

```
Buckets= [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
Emptybuckets=[[1],[],[3]]
```

How could I add these together such that I get:

```
[[1,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,3]]
```

Ive tried `emptybuckets.append(buckets)`, `for` loops (`for x in emptybuckets`...`append`) etc.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: Inside the sublists order doesn't matter. The sublists themselves need to be in the same order however.

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you. Now can I assign this to a new list? I tried to make buckets now equal this new merged list and it doesn't look like it is working. I'm not getting an error but when I do: buckets=[a+b for a, b in zip(buckets,emptybuckets)]           and print=(buckets) I do not get my new list however; print([a+b for a, b in zip(buckets,emptybuckets)] works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to group corresponding indices together, then adding them is easy:

```
[a+b for a, b in zip(Buckets, Emptybuckets)]
# [[1, 2, 3, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
```

---

Or if you want it exactly how it is in your question, just sort each one as you go:

```
[sorted(a+b) for a, b in zip(Buckets, Emptybuckets)]
# [[1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: If the OP wanted to sort the sublist: `[sorted(a+b) for a, b... ]`

Comment: @HaiVu Thanks- I didn't notice that. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Alex Thornton's answer is correct, and I would say that you should include `sorted` if you want the numbers ordered as you state in your question

```
[sorted(a+b) for a, b in zip(Buckets, Emptybuckets)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append the lists using numpy.

```
Buckets= [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
Emptybuckets=[[1],[],[3]]

for item in zip(Buckets,Emptybuckets):
    print(np.append(item[0],item[1],axis=0).astype(int))
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 1]
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3 3]
```